# Neural Network training repeats last trained expected data

Tags: c#, networking

I am trying to make a neural network recognize where a certain pattern is on the screen, by taking an image of a portion of the screen, scaling it down to 25x25 then forwarding it through my neural network.

My issue is after not many training iterations, whatever I trained it last on will be what it repeats, for example, if my last line of code trains it on data where the expected return is (0, 1) like in the code, regardless of what inputs I give it in testing the return will be (0, 1)

First: Neural Network

```
[Serializable]
        class NN
        {
            private const double learningRate = 0.015;

            private List<List<double>> biases;
            private List<List<double>> errors;
            private List<List<double>> values;
            private List<List<List<double>>> weights;

            private Random r = new Random();

            public NN(int[] layers)
            {
                initNeurons(layers);
                initWeights(layers);
            }

            private void initNeurons(int[] layers)
            {
                biases = new List<List<double>>();
                errors = new List<List<double>>();
                values = new List<List<double>>();

                for (int layerIdx = 0; layerIdx < layers.Length; layerIdx++)
                {
                    biases.Add(new List<double>());
                    errors.Add(new List<double>());
                    values.Add(new List<double>());

                    for (int neuronIdx = 0; neuronIdx < layers[layerIdx]; neuronIdx++)
                    {
                        biases[layerIdx].Add(0);
                        errors[layerIdx].Add(0);
                        values[layerIdx].Add(0);
                    }
                }
            }

            private void initWeights(int[] layers)
            {
                weights = new List<List<List<double>>>();

                for (int layerIdx = 0; layerIdx < layers.Length - 1; layerIdx++)
                {
                    weights.Add(new List<List<double>>());

                    for (int neuronIdx = 0; neuronIdx < layers[layerIdx]; neuronIdx++)
                    {
                        weights[layerIdx].Add(new List<double>());

                        for (int nextNeuronIdx = 0; nextNeuronIdx < layers[layerIdx + 1]; nextNeuronIdx++)
                        {
                            weights[layerIdx][neuronIdx].Add(r.NextDouble() - 0.5f);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            private void activateTanh()
            {
                for (int layerIdx = 1; layerIdx < values.Count(); layerIdx++)
                {
                    for (int neuronIdx = 0; neuronIdx < values[layerIdx].Count(); neuronIdx++)
                    {
                        double sum = 0;
                        for (int prevNeuronIdx = 0; prevNeuronIdx < values[layerIdx - 1].Count(); prevNeuronIdx++)
                        {
                            sum += values[layerIdx - 1][prevNeuronIdx] * weights[layerIdx - 1][prevNeuronIdx][neuronIdx];
                        }
                        values[layerIdx][neuronIdx] = Math.Tanh(sum + biases[layerIdx][neuronIdx]);
                    }
                }
            }

            private void activateReLU()
            {
                for (int layerIdx = 1; layerIdx < values.Count(); layerIdx++)
                {
                    for (int neuronIdx = 0; neuronIdx < values[layerIdx].Count(); neuronIdx++)
                    {
                        double sum = 0;
                        for (int prevNeuronIdx = 0; prevNeuronIdx < values[layerIdx - 1].Count(); prevNeuronIdx++)
                        {
                            sum += values[layerIdx - 1][prevNeuronIdx] * weights[layerIdx - 1][prevNeuronIdx][neuronIdx];
                        }
                        values[layerIdx][neuronIdx] = Math.Max(0, sum + biases[layerIdx][neuronIdx]);
                    }
                }
            }

            private void activateSigmoid()
            {
                for (int layerIdx = 1; layerIdx < values.Count(); layerIdx++)
                {
                    for (int neuronIdx = 0; neuronIdx < values[layerIdx].Count(); neuronIdx++)
                    {
                        double sum = 0;
                        for (int prevNeuronIdx = 0; prevNeuronIdx < values[layerIdx - 1].Count(); prevNeuronIdx++)
                        {
                            sum += values[layerIdx - 1][prevNeuronIdx] * weights[layerIdx - 1][prevNeuronIdx][neuronIdx];
                        }
                        values[layerIdx][neuronIdx] = 1 / (1 + Math.Exp(-(sum + biases[layerIdx][neuronIdx])));
                    }
                }
            }

            public double[] getTanhOutput(double[] inputs)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Contracts.Contract.Requires(inputs.Length == values[0].Count());

                for (int neuronIdx = 0; neuronIdx < inputs.Length; neuronIdx++)
                {
                    values[0][neuronIdx] = inputs[neuronIdx];
                }

                activateTanh();

                return values[values.Count() - 1].ToArray();
            }

            public double[] getReLUOutput(double[] inputs)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Contracts.Contract.Requires(inputs.Length == values[0].Count());

                for (int neuronIdx = 0; neuronIdx < inputs.Length; neuronIdx++)
                {
                    values[0][neuronIdx] = inputs[neuronIdx];
                }

                activateReLU();

                return values[values.Count() - 1].ToArray();
            }

            public double[] getSigmoidOutput(double[] inputs)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Contracts.Contract.Requires(inputs.Length == values[0].Count());

                for (int neuronIdx = 0; neuronIdx < inputs.Length; neuronIdx++)
                {
                    values[0][neuronIdx] = inputs[neuronIdx];
                }

                activateSigmoid();

                return values[values.Count() - 1].ToArray();
            }

            public void backPropagateTanh(double[] correctOutput)
            {
                for (int neuronIdx = 0; neuronIdx < values[values.Count() - 1].Count(); neuronIdx++)
                {
                    errors[errors.Count() - 1][neuronIdx] = (correctOutput[neuronIdx] - values[values.Count() - 1][neuronIdx]) * (1 - values[values.Count() - 1][neuronIdx] * values[values.Count() - 1][neuronIdx]);
                }

                for (int layerIdx = values.Count() - 2; layerIdx > 0; layerIdx--)
                {
                    for (int neuronIdx = 0; neuronIdx < values[layerIdx].Count(); neuronIdx++)
                    {
                        double error = 0;
                        for (int nextNeuronIdx = 0; nextNeuronIdx < values[layerIdx + 1].Count(); nextNeuronIdx++)
                        {
                            error += errors[layerIdx + 1][nextNeuronIdx] * weights[layerIdx][neuronIdx][nextNeuronIdx];
                        }
                        errors[layerIdx][neuronIdx] = error * (1 - values[layerIdx][neuronIdx] * values[layerIdx][neuronIdx]);
                    }
                }

                for (int layerIdx = values.Count() - 1; layerIdx > 0; layerIdx--)
                {
                    for (int neuronIdx = 0; neuronIdx < values[layerIdx].Count(); neuronIdx++)
                    {
                        biases[layerIdx][neuronIdx] += errors[layerIdx][neuronIdx] * learningRate;
                        for (int prevNeuronIdx = 0; prevNeuronIdx < values[layerIdx - 1].Count(); prevNeuronIdx++)
                        {
                            weights[layerIdx - 1][prevNeuronIdx][neuronIdx] += values[layerIdx - 1][prevNeuronIdx] * errors[layerIdx][neuronIdx] * learningRate;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            public void backPropagateReLU(double[] correctOutput)
            {
                for (int neuronIdx = 0; neuronIdx < values[values.Count() - 1].Count(); neuronIdx++)
                {
                    errors[errors.Count() - 1][neuronIdx] = (correctOutput[neuronIdx] - values[values.Count() - 1][neuronIdx]) * (values[values.Count() - 1][neuronIdx] > 0 ? 1 : 0);
                }

                for (int layerIdx = values.Count() - 2; layerIdx > 0; layerIdx--)
                {
                    for (int neuronIdx = 0; neuronIdx < values[layerIdx].Count(); neuronIdx++)
                    {
                        double error = 0;
                        for (int nextNeuronIdx = 0; nextNeuronIdx < values[layerIdx + 1].Count(); nextNeuronIdx++)
                        {
                            error += errors[layerIdx + 1][nextNeuronIdx] * weights[layerIdx][neuronIdx][nextNeuronIdx];
                        }
                        errors[layerIdx][neuronIdx] = error * (values[layerIdx][neuronIdx] > 0 ? 1 : 0);
                    }
                }

                for (int layerIdx = values.Count() - 1; layerIdx > 0; layerIdx--)
                {
                    for (int neuronIdx = 0; neuronIdx < values[layerIdx].Count(); neuronIdx++)
                    {
                        biases[layerIdx][neuronIdx] += errors[layerIdx][neuronIdx] * learningRate;
                        for (int prevNeuronIdx = 0; prevNeuronIdx < values[layerIdx - 1].Count(); prevNeuronIdx++)
                        {
                            weights[layerIdx - 1][prevNeuronIdx][neuronIdx] += values[layerIdx - 1][prevNeuronIdx] * errors[layerIdx][neuronIdx] * learningRate;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            public void backPropagateSigmoid(double[] correctOutput)
            {
                for (int neuronIdx = 0; neuronIdx < values[values.Count() - 1].Count(); neuronIdx++)
                {
                    errors[errors.Count() - 1][neuronIdx] = (correctOutput[neuronIdx] - values[values.Count() - 1][neuronIdx]) * values[values.Count() - 1][neuronIdx] * (1 - values[values.Count() - 1][neuronIdx]);
                }

                for (int layerIdx = values.Count() - 2; layerIdx > 0; layerIdx--)
                {
                    for (int neuronIdx = 0; neuronIdx < values[layerIdx].Count(); neuronIdx++)
                    {
                        double error = 0;
                        for (int nextNeuronIdx = 0; nextNeuronIdx < values[layerIdx + 1].Count(); nextNeuronIdx++)
                        {
                            error += errors[layerIdx + 1][nextNeuronIdx] * weights[layerIdx][neuronIdx][nextNeuronIdx];
                        }
                        errors[layerIdx][neuronIdx] = error * values[layerIdx][neuronIdx] * (1 - values[layerIdx][neuronIdx]);
                    }
                }

                for (int layerIdx = values.Count() - 1; layerIdx > 0; layerIdx--)
                {
                    for (int neuronIdx = 0; neuronIdx < values[layerIdx].Count(); neuronIdx++)
                    {
                        biases[layerIdx][neuronIdx] += errors[layerIdx][neuronIdx] * learningRate;
                        for (int prevNeuronIdx = 0; prevNeuronIdx < values[layerIdx - 1].Count(); prevNeuronIdx++)
                        {
                            weights[layerIdx - 1][prevNeuronIdx][neuronIdx] += values[layerIdx - 1][prevNeuronIdx] * errors[layerIdx][neuronIdx] * learningRate;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            public void TrainTanh(double[] inputs, double[] correctOutput)
            {
                getTanhOutput(inputs);
                backPropagateTanh(correctOutput);
            }

            public void TrainReLU(double[] inputs, double[] correctOutput)
            {
                getReLUOutput(inputs);
                backPropagateReLU(correctOutput);
            }

            public void TrainSigmoid(double[] inputs, double[] correctOutput)
            {
                getSigmoidOutput(inputs);
                backPropagateSigmoid(correctOutput);
            }

            public void Save()
            {
                using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("brain.dat", FileMode.Create))
                {
                    System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
                    binaryFormatter.Serialize(fileStream, this);
                }
            }

            public void Load()
            {
                using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("brain.dat", FileMode.Open))
                {
                    System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
                    NN brain = (NN)binaryFormatter.Deserialize(fileStream);
                    this.values = brain.values;
                    this.weights = brain.weights;
                    this.biases = brain.biases;
                    this.errors = brain.errors;
                }
            }
```

The training code:

```
private static void TrainITIguess(NN brain)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                Console.Title = $"Done: {Math.Round((double)j + (double)1 / (double)10)}%  ({j} / 100000)";

                DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

                Parallel.For(0, zeroTrainingData.Count, i =>
                {
                    brain.TrainTanh(zeroTrainingData[i].ToArray(), new double[] { 0, 0 });
                });
                Parallel.For(0, leftTrainingData.Count, i =>
                {
                    brain.TrainTanh(leftTrainingData[i].ToArray(), new double[] { -1, 0 });
                });
                Parallel.For(0, rightTrainingData.Count, i =>
                {
                    brain.TrainTanh(rightTrainingData[i].ToArray(), new double[] { 1, 0 });
                });
                Parallel.For(0, topTrainingData.Count, i =>
                {
                    brain.TrainTanh(topTrainingData[i].ToArray(), new double[] { 0, -1 });
                });
                //Parallel.For(0, bottomTrainingData.Count, i =>
                //{
                    //brain.TrainTanh(bottomTrainingData[i].ToArray(), new double[] { 0, 1 });
                //});

                Console.WriteLine($"Time: {DateTime.Now - start}");
            }
        }
```

the training data is just grayscale pixels turned into doubles

```
for (int x = 0; x < scaled.Width; x++)
                    {
                        for (int y = 0; y < scaled.Height; y++)
                        {
                            inputs.Add((scaled.GetPixel(x, y).R + scaled.GetPixel(x, y).G + scaled.GetPixel(x, y).B) / 3 / 255);
                        }
                    }
```